# Optional Parameter becoming required in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, parameters

I would like to make a python script (.pyt) where i have 2 input parameters:

If the first parameter (which is a boolean) is set TRUE, therefore it is checked, the 2nd parameter should become required (if not, the 2nd parameter should be optional).

This is the used code so far:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="BooleanTest",
    name="in_features",
    datatype="Boolean",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Test",
    name="testfield",
    datatype="Field",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input")

    params = [param0,param1]

    return params



def updateParameters(self):
    if self.params[0].value == "True":
        self.params[1].parameterType = "Required"
    else:
        self.params[1].parameterType = "Optional"

    return
```

what am I doing wrong? I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `parameterType` property is read-only; take a look at the Python toolbox help page [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Customizing_tool_behavior_in_a_Python_toolbox/00150000002m000000/).

In other words, you cannot make a parameter required or optional on-the-fly; the closest you could get is to enable/disable the parameter with the `.enabled` property.

Other things: use GPBoolean instead of Boolean - refer to this [page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Defining_parameter_data_types_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000035000000/) for data types; `updateParameters()` takes in `params` as an argument - yours doesn't; don't supply the `self.` before params inside the function. Look at the [samples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Defining_parameter_data_types_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000035000000/) at Python toolbox Help.

Complete code:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="BooleanTest",
        name="in_features",
        datatype="GPBoolean",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Test",
        name="testfield",
        datatype="Field",
        parameterType="Optional",
        direction="Input",
        enabled=False)

    parameters = [param0,param1]

    return parameters

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    if parameters[0].altered:
        if parameters[0].value == True:
            parameters[1].enabled = True
        else:
            parameters[1].enabled = False
        return
```

Alternatively, you can implement the solution you need by using the error messages, which provides exactly the same behavior as you need.

```
def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    if parameters[0].value == True:
        parameters[1].setErrorMessage("You must supply a value for this parameter")
    return
```

You don't need to use the `updateParameters` at all then.

Complete code:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="BooleanTest",
        name="in_features",
        datatype="GPBoolean",
        parameterType="Optional",
        direction="Input")

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Test",
        name="testfield",
        datatype="Field",
        parameterType="Optional",
        direction="Input")

    parameters = [param0,param1]

    return parameters

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    if parameters[0].value == True:
        parameters[1].setErrorMessage("You must supply a value for the parameter X")
    return
```

If user has checked the check box, she won't be able to execute the tool unless she provides some value for the second parameter.

Comment: thank you, would this task be possible in a normal python script (not a python toolbox)?

Comment: No, it's not possible to change the parameter type there either. But you can check whether the tool can be run by checking that the param1 is not emtpy when param0 is True. This is legal

Comment: Alternatively, you can supply a default value for param1 which will be used whenever the param0 is checked.

Comment: @Duddel, I've provided an alternative workaround which seems to do exactly what you need.